# flickity carusel no control over margin between images in carusel

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flickity

I have created the following [codepane](https://codesandbox.io/s/flickity-changin-margin-example-s5gws) using the react-flickity-component to show case images:

[image: initial view]
when i resize the browser the margin between the images changes and disappears

[image: after resize]

no matter what i do next except refreshing the page the margin between the images will be gone

if i add a `margin-right:10px` to the carousel-cell the the margin doesn't disappear [codepan](https://codesandbox.io/s/flickity-changin-margin-example-yk0xj):

[image: after margin right]

but the margin size is not consistent if i resize the browser window:

[image: with margin right and resize]

it can be larger or smaller when i resize the browser into different sizes

any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

May be late to the party here. Just add `margin-right: 10px` to your `.carousel-cell` class in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try padding: 1%, or use % in your margins

Comment: using % dosen't help, i want the margin to be consistent on init and after resizing the browser windows. using % gives different sizes of spaces when resizing the window